# How to debug Angular SPA in either vs2019 or vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, single-page-application, angular7, visual-studio-2019

This may be a stupid question, but I can't figure out how to debug my whole application in either vscode or vs2019 community.  If I use vs2019, I can debug the api, controllers, etc just fine, but can't debug the typescript or js.  If I use vscode, I can debug the typescript, but it doesn't make the calls to the api so the app locks up...

Any suggestions?  I've tried the google extension in vscode but still can't debug the typescript code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You do it in the Chrome dev tools, hit F12 in Chrome and go to the sources tab. Hit ctrl-p to search for the source file. You can set break point in the TypeScript.

Comment: I feel so stupid.  That was easy, I couldn't figure out how to get the .ts file to show in the debugger.  Thanks a bunch.